# How does this Python decorator work?

Tags: python, decorator

I was looking at some lazy loading property decorators in Python and happened across this example (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/363602-lazy-property-evaluation/):

```
class Lazy(object):
    def __init__(self, calculate_function):
        self._calculate = calculate_function

    def __get__(self, obj, _=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        value = self._calculate(obj)
        setattr(obj, self._calculate.func_name, value)
        return value

# Sample use:

class SomeClass(object):

    @Lazy
    def someprop(self):
        print 'Actually calculating value'
        return 13

o = SomeClass()
o.someprop
o.someprop
```

My question is, how does this work?  My understanding of decorators is that they must be callable (so either a function or a call that implements `__call__`), but `Lazy` here clearly is not and if I try `Lazy(someFunc)()` it raises an exception as expected.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When an attribute named `someprop` is accessed on instance `o` of class `SomeClass`, if `SomeClass` contains a *descriptor* named `o`, then that descriptor's class's `__get__` method is used.  For more on descriptors, see [this guide](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm).  Don't let the fact that `Lazy` is here used, syntactically, as a decorator, blind you to the fact that its instances are descriptors, because `Lazy` itself has a `__get__` method.

The decorator syntax

```
    @Lazy
    def someprop(self):
       ...
```

is no more, and no less, than syntax sugar for:

```
    def someprop(self):
       ...
    someprop = Lazy(someprop)
```

The constraints on `Lazy` are no different when it's used with decorator syntax or directly: it must accept `someprop` (a function) as its argument -- no constraints whatsoever on what it returns.  Here, `Lazy` is a class so it returns an instance of itself, and has a `__get__` special method so that instance is a descriptor (so said method gets called when the `someprop` attribute is accessed on the instance `o` of class `SomeClass`) -- that's all there is to it, no more, and no less.